# Questions from novices

Tags: discussion

I want to ask the following question on Biology Stack Exchange. However, I don't know whether I can post it without it being closed.

My question is:

Suppose a group of cells have the same shape. Will they have the same layout, or is there something else affecting layout. If so, then what is it. How do the instructions found in DNA manage cell layout? Can you give me some examples.

Now, my question, I realize, might be too broad. And I am just a novice.

However, I would like to know whether I can get some answers (perhaps with some pictures, including pictures of cell complexes, and of molecules, or proteins, including proteins on cell walls, that would allow for different cell cluster configurations to take place).

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer**

As nobody has answered it, I have edited the question to make it more generally relevant to Meta. The following is just my personal opinion as a long-standing member of this site. But I am not a site moderator and others may well have different views.

**General Remarks**

I understand why someone would wish to check whether their question is appropriate before posting — they wish to respect our community and it can be unpleasant if people vote to close (not ban) one’s question. But none of us can say for certain whether a particular question will be considered off-topic. We certainly suggest that posters read the Help, especially the [Help on Asking Good Questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What Questions should I avoid asking?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), but, in addition, it may be useful to list and comment on the criteria on which questions may be deemed off-topic. (And I can give you my personal opinion on which of these I think may apply to the question cited.)

**How Questions are closed**

As users of other SE sites will be aware, questions can be closed by members who deem them off-topic. The motivation for people who do this differs, but in general is to maintain the quality of the site so it continues to attract questions appropriate to **“a question and answer site for biology researchers, academics, and students”**.

On this site five votes to close are generally required (the moderators can override this if they see fit) and only members who have accumulated a reputation of 3000 can cast close votes. (So if I vote to close your question, it will only be closed if four other regular users think likewise.)

**Criteria for closing a question**

Users who feel a question should be closed must specify one of a limited selection of reasons. Some of these are common to most SE sites:

DUPLICATE
One should check for similar questions before posting, but I don’t think this is a problem here.

LACKS DETAIL OR CLARITY
This is very common. The poster is wrapped up in his topic and assumes that others will know what he is talking about. I feel this is one of the major problems with the question here. It talks about cells (please not in bunches) having *the same shape*. What is meant here? Individual cells of the same type like fibroblasts that all tend to be elongated, or cells of different types (fibroblasts and myoblasts(?) say) with a similar shape but different lineage and function. However, even less clear is *“Will they have the same layout”*. What is meant by *“layout”*? I have absolutely no idea. It does not correspond to any term used in cell or molecular biology and suggests the question is coming from a non-biologist (of which more later).

NEEDS MORE FOCUS
The poster feels that the question may be too broad. As I don’t understand it, I cannot say, but many questions from non-biologists are impossibly broad and impossible to answer. One can ask, for example, how the shape of a cell is determined, and that is a valid question, but I doubt that we know the answer, and what we do know would fill a book. Such naïve questions can be avoided by prior research — Google for terms like “determination of cell shape”.

OPINION BASED
This is not the problem here, but is in many cases, especially with questions starting with “why” (e.g. “why do spiders have eight legs and insects six”) or, even more so, “why not” (e.g. “why did we not evolve armour plating”). Often such questions come from people who regard biology as a subject anyone can join in, and would like to base a discussion on their idle thoughts. SE Biology is Q&A site where objective answers are possible. It is not a discussion site.

A COMMUNITY-SPECIFIC REASON
Some of the community-specific reasons need little comment. Chemistry questions should be submitted to SE Chemistry, and personal medical questions are not allowed and will be quickly closed by moderators. The category most frequently used — and most frequently misunderstood — is **Homework Questions**. At its simplest, this category is used for questions that are literally homework, and there is a special [Help entry](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) regarding them. But it is also used for questions that do not show any evidence of effort on the part of the poster (*see* [“Search, and research”](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)). And when there is a question of this sort that appears to have come from someone who does not seem to fit any of the categories [“biology researchers, academics, and students”](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) it is a convenient way to dispose of it. I would say that such a lack of obvious research applies to the question here.

**Final advice to the Poster**

Clarify your question, do some research, and then post. If people ask for specific clarification you can always revise it further.